# How to bypass "RUN fsck MANUALLY" boot error

Tags: boot, hard-drive, shutdown, fsck

By bypass I mean automatically just do it even if it causes file problems. The long and short here is that I have about 60 headless servers running Camera systems with 4-8 drives in them spread out across the country. Theres nothing physically wrong with the drives. this will happen on a 3 day old system or a 3 year old system, its a matter of the fs table being open for writing at the time of the power loss. Sometimes a power outage occurs and the on-site UPS runs out before the safe shutdown completes and theres some filesystem damage. these things are writing constantly so it takes about 3-5 mins to clear the write cache out and the ups safe shutdown trigger takes too long. I need these things to come back up without having to fly or send someone out there to fix them. this error is what comes up:

[image: FS Error]

The command needed to fix it is also pictured and takes all of 30 seconds. is there a way for me to tell ubuntu to just do this automatically if necessary. I don't care if it corrupts a few video files, I'm okay with a small storage loss. I don't want a 3 day storage gap because someone needs to be sent on site for 30 seconds.

Any help appreciated!